# How to change the visibility of a div when browser reloads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the main div hidden when someone hits the refresh button and then after sometime making the main div visible. The reload detection code is working but why the div isn't getting hidden?
CSS

```
#Web_1920__1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3554px;
    height: 2346px;
    border: 0px grey solid;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//check for Navigation Timing API support
if (window.performance) 
{
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
console.info(performance.navigation.type);
if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) 
{
  console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  
  document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.visibility = "hidden";

  setInterval(function() 
    { 
        document.getElementById("Web_1920__1").style.visibility = "visible";

    }, 700); 
} 
else 
{
  console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Setting the visibility hidden outside setInterval function not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: This basically worked for me as you have it. However, I had to set the timing parameter to 7000 (7 seconds) to see it. Also, don' you want to use setTimeout instead of setInterval to do this just once?

Comment: Yeah setTimeout will do the job but in my case using a setTimeout to hide then again using setTimeout or setInterval to show the div works... But it's not still good.  I can see some jitters. I want to hide the div as fast as possible. But not getting that ...